# Unable to start java.exe: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I recently started using FlashDevelop from Adobe Flash Creator and when I compile code I get the following error.

> Unable to start java.exe: The system cannot find the file specified

Anyone know what could be causing this and how it might be resolved?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have Java Runtime Environment installed, and all the paths set correctly - especially `PATH`(to the jre/bin) and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables.

Comment: could you elaborate on how to check PATH and JAVA_HOME?

Comment: and what should JAVA_HOME be set to?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre something like this @avorum

Comment: check the path and Java_Home as this in command prompt: echo %PATH% and echo %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: PATH returned a number of paths, most of which seem random but the last one points to /Java/jdk 1.7.../bin

Comment: JAVA_HOME returns the /Java/jdk 1.7.../jre

Comment: @avorum type this in command prompt: java -version and tell me what you get

Comment: java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: @avorum Are you sure the FlashDevelop version you have supports 64 bit JVM?

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but FlashDevelop is working fine on my laptop which is brand new, so I'm pretty sure it's 64bit and I installed FlashDevelop at about the same time for both systems.

Comment: Looked and apparently the 32bit Java is required.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to the Flex SDK\bin folder!
2. Open jvm.config file!
3. Search the line "java.home=".
4. Write the address to the jre\bin folder on the line!!
   Example: java.home=C:\Program Files\jre7\bin
5. If #4 don't work, do this!!

java.home=C:\Program Files\jre7

That'll do fine!!

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you are using Java 1.6+ 32-bit runtime (JRE), not 64-bit.

It can be downloaded from here: (which is actually not that obvious from FlashDevelop)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jre-6u43-oth-JPR